# Mariadb gives interface error on trying to populate the database using python

Tags: python, json, mariadb

I am trying to create JSON profiles in mariadb. On exactly 21-22% of the completion of updating the database, mariadb throws INTERFACE ERROR without any further information.

I checked that it is not because of the data point by selecting different orders of data(ASC, DESC). It always stops at 20-22%. If I am running the code again, without clearing the tables, it runs 100% successfully.

But if I run it with clearing the tables, the same problem persists.

Code:

```py
# analysis.py
def updateSpecific(data, name):
    try:
        cursor = mydb.Cursor()
        
        # Getting the column name and value to update in mariadb
        columnname = COLUMNNAMES[name]
        columnvalue = data[columnname]
        
        if columnvalue == None:
            return
        
        cursor.execute("select * from " + name +" where " + columnname + " = %s ", (columnvalue,))
        dataInDB = cursor.fetchone()
        
        newentry = False
        if dataInDB == None:
            newentry = True
            newdata = {}
        else: # if not a  new entry in the db, load it from cursor fetch
            newdata = json.loads(dataInDB[2])
        
        # Append the new data, push the new data to db
        newdata = getupdatedDB(name, newdata, data)
        newdata = json.dumps(newdata)
        if newentry:
            cursor.execute("insert into " + name + "(" + columnname +", total, data) values (%s, %s ,%s)", (columnvalue, 1, newdata))
        else:
            cursor.execute("update " + name + " set total = %s, data = %s where " +columnname + " = %s", ((dataInDB[1]+1), newdata, columnvalue))
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        print(data,name,columnvalue)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    mydb.commit()
```

The error is

```
Updating...:  22%|█████████████▉                                                  | 2183/10054 [02:46<11:48, 11.11it/s]
Error:
Updating...:  22%|█████████████▉                                                  | 2184/10054 [02:46<10:00, 13.10it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analysis.py", line 155, in <module>
    updateDB(data_dict)
  File "analysis.py", line 130, in updateDB
    updateLoc(data)
  File "analysis.py", line 115, in updateLoc
    updateSpecific(data, COLUMNNAME)
  File "analysis.py", line 90, in updateSpecific
    mydb.commit()
mariadb.InterfaceError
```

When I tried to move mydb.commit() inside the try block, this is the error:

```
Error:
Error: Invalid parameter number
Error: Invalid parameter number
Error: Unknown prepared statement handler (6710628) given to mysqld_stmt_reset
Error: Invalid parameter number
Error: Unknown prepared statement handler (6710628) given to mysqld_stmt_reset
Error: Invalid parameter number
```

and the code stops after this.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB Connector/Python do you use (and which version of MariaDB Connector/C  - print(mariadb.mariadbapi_version)) ?

Comment: mariadb version: 10.5
mariadb.mariadbapi_version(Mariadb Connector/C): 3.2.6
mariadb-python-connector: 1.0.11

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the same issue as in [CONPY-197](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONPY-197) which is still not closed due to lack of user feedback.

However, the MariaDB Connector/Python 1.0 series are not supported anymore, most of the cursor implementation was rewritten in 1.1 so I would highly recommend to upgrade your python module.

Also Connector/C 3.2 is discontinued (in newer server packages it was replaced with C/C 3.3), so you also have to update Connector/C before upgrading MariaDB Connector/Python. Minimum required version is Connector/C 3.3.1, better to install actual version 3.3.3.

If the problem still persists, please file a bug in the [MariaDB issue tracker](https://jira.mariadb.org/).